# Find two parametrized curves $c,v:I\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ that produce a Möbius band as ruled surface

Tags: differential-geometry

> Where a ruled surface is $f:I\times R\rightarrow\mathbb R^3$ defined by

$$f(s,t):=c(t)+sv(t)$$

Do I have to take it from the parametric equation i.e. $c(t):=(R\cos(t),R\sin t,0)$ and $v(t):=(\cos(t)\cos(t/2),\sin(t)\cos(t/2),\sin(t/2))$ is that correct ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your choice of $c$ and $v$ is correct. And it is not hard  to find $c$ and $v$ directly from the geometric concept of the Möbius strip, without having a ready-made parametric equation. Mark the "median" of the strip, a closed curve that was an axis of symmetry of the rectangle from which the Möbius strip is glued. As a point moves along the median,  the tangent vector (say, pointing to the right of the velocity vector) rotates in such a way that one trip around the median results in rotation by $\pi$. So the angular speed of tangent vector rotation is $1/2$ of the angular speed of the point itself.

This is captured in $c(t)=(\cos t,\sin t,0)$ (the parametric equation of the median) and $v(t)=(\cos t \cos (t/2), \sin t \cos (t/2), \sin (t/2))$: here we have the exterior normal to the circle rotated by the angle $t/2$.

In general,  $(x\cos \theta,y\cos \theta,  \sqrt{x^2+y^2}\sin \theta)$ rotates the planar vector $(x,y,0)$ by $\theta$ radian around a horizontal axis. This leads to a generalization of the Möbius strip:
$$v(t)=(\cos t \cos (nt/2), \sin t \cos (nt/2), \sin (nt/2))$$
for some integer $n\ge 0$. This ruled surface is  glued from a rectangle with $n$ twists.